# Difference between sampling rate of ADC and Sampling frequency

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I was referring to following codes given in reference: https://github.com/OpenLabTools/RPi_ADS1115/blob/master/code/continuous_read_adc.py

Line 18, asks for user defined sampling frequency.
And then in Line 43, this 'user defined sampling frequency ' is used to define time step  ( as mentioned in line 22) and save it in csv file.

Line 19, asks for sapling rate (sps) of the ADC convertor i.e. ADS1115 (which can be any one of 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 250, 475, 860 sps).
And then In line 27, ADC conversion is done wrt to this sps as mentioned in line 19.

However, as per my understanding, sapling frequency and sampling rate are same.

So how can we have two different inputs ?

If somebody could please let me know where is my understanding going wrong, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the Github repository owner?  I have had luck in the past getting questions answered with this approach.

Comment: From what I can see, the code samples something and puts it into a CSV. So the sampling frequency is the number of data points per second in the CSV. On the other hand, the sampling rate is the real sapling rate that your ADC is using. That is, sampling frequency <= sampling rate.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for your valuable feedback. I have observed that if I put sps=860 and frequency=5Hz, then I get equal time step in my csv file i.e. (timeStep=1/frequency=1/5=0.2s).However, if I set frequency=860Hz, keeping sps=860, the time step I get in csv file is highly erroneous. Expected should have beeen 1/860=0.001s. But I get 0.0005s<timeStep<0.003s. What could be the possible reasons for this? Is the hardware/software of RPi/ADC115 is not supportive to record high data at frequency=860 Hz? Could you please give your views on this.